# Generating points not within the range of each other?

Tags: python, math, graphics

I am trying to generate a set of points that do not fall within the range of each other in a fixed area. My approach is given below:

```
import collections
from random import uniform

X = 100.0
Y = 100.0
points = 10
radius = 10

def in_circle(c_x, c_y, radius, x, y):
    dist_squared = (c_x - x)**2 + (c_y - y)**2
    return dist_squared <= radius ** 2

current = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [])

threshold = 0    

for point in range(1, points+1):
    cX = uniform(1.0, X)
    cY = uniform(1.0, Y)

    for cur in current:
        while in_circle(current[cur][0], current[cur][1], 2*radius, cX, cY):
          cX = uniform(1.0, X)
          cY = uniform(1.0, X)

          threshold += 1
          if threshold >= 1e+05:
              print "Cannot satisfy constraints"
              sys.exit(1)

    threshold = 0

    current[point] = [cX, cY]
    print cX, cY
```

Is there a good way to terminate this algorithm without making it enter an infinite loop? I do have a threshold check but are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://devmag.org.za/2009/05/03/poisson-disk-sampling/) about poisson disk sampling may be interesting to you.  The author explains a strategy for selecting points that aren't too close to each other, and even provides sample code in a few languages, including Python.

The problem with the strategy you outlined is, as you noted, that if you want to select a lot of points, or you want the points to be quite far apart, the performance can become atrocious.  The poisson disk scheme has better performance characteristics, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Can you subdivide the area into squares with *side >= minimum allowed distance between points* and then just pick a few of them at random?

For example, these are your point-bounding squares, "numbered" from 0 through j:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
a b c d e
f g h i j
```

Then you make an array of the square indices (0 through j in this example), [randomly shuffle it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), ending up with, say, bc4j25e1670dfgh89ai3, and take from its beginning as many indices as you need points, e.g. 5: bc4j2. Then you place your points in the centers (or maybe top-left corners) of the chosen squares:

```
0 1 * 3 *
5 6 7 8 9
a * * d e
f g h i *
```

Answer (score 2):

This class of problem is known as [circle packing](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html). The article on mathworld indicates that the densest known packings for the unit square are known (and this problem can be transformed into that one by scaling x and y). The images in that article demonstrate two dense sphere packings (square and hexagonal).

As to whether you can insert a new circle, a [voronoi diagram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagram.html) has the potential to be useful as a measure of maximum remaining unsampled area. Other approximate methods assessing unoccupied area such as quad trees or spatial hashing may also be sufficient in some cases